# Change Pivot Point of Bone Without Changing Child Bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, transforms

There is a bone in an already completed and weight painted rig that I want to change the pivot point for. If I move the head in edit mode, the child bones move as well.

How do I change the pivot point without affecting the child bones?

[image: Bone in Pose Mode]
[image: Bone in Edit Mode]
[image: Bone Pivot Point Changed.]
[image: Bone in pose mode. Some of its child bones in the lips have moved and made the mouth deformed. Manual translation and snap to cursor, both keeping and not keeping offset, yield the same results.]

Comment: could you please show some screenshots to make it more understandable? thanks

Comment: I've added images.

Comment: if you move the parent in Edit mode, the children won't move in Edit mode, but any rotation of the parent in Pose mode will affect the children differently than before as the rotation axis is completely different, maybe that's what you're talking about? I may miss something but don't see any easy solution